# How to select from list and click submit button then go to link "in HTML"

Tags: html, list, hyperlink, submit

I found this code for my project. I want to change this to open website with click on submit button

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="cars">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site" name="site">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

for example: when select "Google" from list, with click on "submit" button open "www.google.com" that exist on "action_page.php"

I dont have "action_page.php" code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I modified your **html** code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="get">
  <label for="cars">Choose a Site:</label>
  <select id="site" name="site">
    <option value="Google">Google</option>
    <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" id="button" >Submit</button>

<script src="script1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Made a button outside of the form and referenced the external **js** file **script1.js**

Then I created the **js** file and added this code to it:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('site');

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    var value = select.value
    if (value == "Google")
    {
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
    }
    else if (value == "Yahoo")
    {
        window.location.href = "https://www.yahoo.com/";
    }
    else if (value == "MSN")
    {
        window.location.href = "https://www.msn.com/";
    }
};
```

It finds the **select** tag and the button from the **html** script, checks if the button was pressed and redirects to the corresponding website based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) . Can you explain **more** about it? what can I do for open websites in **new window**? , I want more than **10 lists**, how can I do that? "**getElementById('site')**" and "**getElementById("button")**" thanks again :)

Comment: Hi. 
Use **window.open(url)** to open in a new window.
To add more lists just add more **option** tags and more **if statements**  with the tag value in its condition.
With **getElementById("site")** and **getElementById("button")** I search for elements with the id **site** and **button** in the **html** code.

Comment: Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: How can use the "submit button" **in front of** the "List" instead of **bottom**?